# Linked List constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a constructor for a `Deck` class which has only one field: a pointer to a `node` class object. A `node` has two fields, a card object and a pointer to another node (linked list).

I'm trying to build a deck of cards using this construct but when I print it, it only displays one card, leading me to believe that the constructor doesn't work properly.

My printing method works fine, I've tested it with other examples.  I'm intentionally starting the deck with the same card twice as I was going to remove it later.

```
Deck::Deck(){
    node* phead;
    phead = new node(Card("A","Heart"));
    node* curr;
    node* next;
    curr = phead->next;

    string suits[4] {"Heart", "Spade", "Club", "Diamond"};
    string values[13] {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
            curr = new node();
            curr->card = Card(values[j], suits[i]);
            next = curr->next;
            curr = next;
        }
    }
    curr=NULL;
    deck = phead;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You're not linking between your nodes properly.

Comment: Should not be 'curr=phead' at the end of your variable declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `curr = phead->next`, try `phead->next = curr`

Your code appears to be setting the value of curr to the value of phead->next, which is never being changed in this code.

Setting phead->next to curr will make it so that the phead list contains the node which is being created in the curr value, adding curr to your linked list.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it, linked list are a little tricky